# CKAN: How can I have public metadata on a private dataset?

Tags: metadata, ckan

I have created a ckan plugin that adds some extra functionality according to my team's needs. I would also like to do the following: Allow logged in users to view the metadata of private datasets, but not allow them to download the resources unless they are allowed to, according to their rights on the platform. How do I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Permission Labels
https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IPermissionLabels